# Show all Images from Array with Smarty

Tags: php, image, smarty

I want to load all images from a certain folder into an array and then display it with Smarty on my page.

So what I've done is this

```
$getAllImages = glob("images/profile/" . $userid . "/*.*");
$smarty->assign('images', $getAllImages);
```

Note: When I do this

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($getAllImages); $i++)
echo $getAllImages[$i];
```

I get the image path of the files like `"images/profile/1/avatar.png"`

What I want to now is to display it on my .html-page so I can display all images

I've done this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
{foreach from=images item=res}
  <img src="{$res}">
{/foreach}
```

This only results into `<img src="images">`

Comment: Please double-check with the manual: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach - you likely just have a typo (a missing dollar sign maybe?).

Comment: Hint: `from=images` - missing `$` before `images`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a variable in smarty it has to be access in .tpl using $ symbol hence change your code to this

```
{foreach from=$images item=res}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now.. I'm working with smarty since 3 months, how could I not see this?

Comment: That is fine @loomie. Happens, Programmers life is filled with stupidity like that :) Cheers Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `images` as a variable. so you have to use `$images` in tpl file

```
{foreach from=$images item=res}
  <img src="{$res}">
{/foreach}
```

For more details Check [foreach manual](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)

Comment: I feel so stupid now.. I'm working with smarty since 3 months, how could I not see this?